# NodeJS Docker container can't connect to MySQL (on host)

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, ubuntu-20.04

I have a **nodejs** trying to `mysql.createPool({host: 'host.docker.internal', ...})`
but I got

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
> at Protocol._enqueue (.../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
> at Protocol.handshake (.../node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
> at PoolConection.connect (.../node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
> at Pool.getConnection (.../node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)

Could there be a bug in the mysql client in the node:12-alpine image?
I've checked that `docker exec -it ... ping host.docker.internal` is indeed resolved as 172.17.0.1.
Why is `mysql.createPool({host: 'host.docker.internal', ...})` trying to look for 127.0.0.1:3306?

I was able to reach another container on the same host with `host.docker.internal`. I believe it proves that I have run `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` correctly.

I am also able to query MySQL by running the js standalone with `node xyz.js` on both *localhost* and *127.0.0.1*.

What am I missing?

I am trying all these on **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**, **Docker 20.10.8**, **MySQL 8.0.26** (installed on the host).

*************************** P.S. ***************************
I built another image with 172.10.0.1 hardcoded in `createPool()` and run the js in a container, but to no avail.

Then I did a crazy experiment by running the js standalone `node xyz.js` on the host with `mysql.createPool({host: '172.17.0.1', ...})` it would give

> connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.1:3306`

**BUT** if I edit `/etc/hosts` and add `172.17.0.1 host.docker.internal` (on the host) and `mysql.createPool({host: 'host.docker.internal', ...})`, the js could connect to MySQL standalone!

Comment: Could you add your `docker-compose` or your run command?

Comment: Hi Joseph, it was the docker run command that I was using, along with -p 80:5050 --name --restart and --add-host parameters. (5050 being the containerized port the J's is listening to)

Answer (score 0):

If you use 127.0.0.1 then the container would try to connect on localhost within the container, but mysql is running on the docker host.

You can try to connect to it on the network interface added by docker, you can check that by using the command `ip a`, please see following output

```
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:53:81:5c:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
```

In my case I would use below url to connect to mysql:

```
172.17.0.1:3306
```

Comment: but he mentioned that he used `host.docker.internal` as should be and it worked for him with another container, are you sure this doesn't changes your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried 172.17.0.1 too but didn't work. Which makes me wonder, how did host.docker.internal got translated to 127.0.0.1 and ended up with that error

Comment: Was the same internal ip (172.17.0.1) listed when you entered the command 'ip a'?

Comment: hi @AshishRanjan , for the record, yes my docker0 gateway is also 172.17.0.1

Comment: One crazy thing that I did, was to run the js standalone `node xyz.js` with `mysql.createPool({host: '172.17.0.1', ...})` unlike localhost/127.0.0.1 which were successful, it returned the `ECONNREFUSED` error
**BUT**
when I edit (on the host) `/etc/hosts` and add `172.17.0.1 host.docker.internal` and `node xyz.js` with `mysql.createPool({host: 'host.docker.internal', ...})`, standalone js works!
What is going on?!

Answer (score 0):

I am running a docker-compose NodeJS application which connects to the Linux host MySQL database on port 3306. To resolve the errors described:

- Specifically for **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** & **mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.32-MariaDB**, the configuration is found in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

  - *If you are not sure where the config is located, run the following to locate:*

    ```
     grep -rnw 'bind-address' /etc/mysql/
    ```
- Proceed to edit the mysql server configuration, replacing `127.0.0.1` with `0.0.0.0` as described on Docker forum [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/container-cannot-connect-to-the-hosts-mysql-database/3493).

```sh
sudo vim /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

- make the following change differential:

  ```
   - bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
   + bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
  ```
- and restart mysql (MariaDB)

```sh
sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

On running `docker-compose`, the container which previously failed is now able to access the localhost SQL database!